# Insert into DB based on a Join -> Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working on a roll format for a laravel project.

I have successfully created the roll, and can update the roll status in the roll table which looks like this

```
|id|roll_id|member_id|status|created_at|updated_at|
```

One of my status is "Present/Voucher" using funds off a Voucher

I have the Voucher Table

```
|id|member_id|voucher|date|balance|created_at|updated_at|
```

When a user clicks on the present/voucher icon in the roll, the following is called in the controller

```
public function voucher($id)
{    
    $r = Roll::find($id);

    if ($r != null)
 {
    $r->status = "V";
    $r->save();

     return redirect(action('RollController@index'))->with ('success', 'Member Paid with Vocuher');
 }
 return redirect(action('RollController@index'));    
}
```

This works perfect, what I would like to know is how to insert a record into my Voucher table, while I can find the id record in the roll table, I need to pull that member_id so I can add this into the voucher table

For example if the Roll Record looks like this

```
|id|roll_id|member_id|Status|
|20|2|13|V|
```

I need to grab 13 are the Member_ID from roll record 20, so I can insert in the vouchers table

```
|id|member_id|voucher|date|balance
|2|13|Weekly Fees|currdate|-10
```

Please note the 10 is also stored in a settings table, so if I can grab from that table that would be great

Settings  Table:

```
|id|Setting|Value|
|1|weekly Subs|10|
```

Thanks

Comment: The formatting of this posts makes it very confusing to understand, better structure would help people giving good  answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first define [model relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships).

**Member**

```
class Member extends Model {
    public function vouchers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Voucher');
    }
}
```

**Roll**

```
class Roll extends Model {
    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Member');
    }
}
```

**Voucher**

```
class Voucher extends Model {
    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Member');
    }

    public function setting()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Setting');
    }
}
```

Then you can execute fluently in controller, you should also use `lockForUpdate` and `DB::transaction`

```
public function voucher($id)
{    
    DB::transaction(function () use ($id) {
        $roll = Roll::lockForUpdate()->find($id);

        if ($roll != null) {
            $roll->status = "V";
            $roll->save();

            $voucher = new Voucher();
            $voucher->member_id = $roll->member_id;
            ...

            // Correct me if I am wrong, form your table structure it looks like you linked table voucher and setting with 'value'
            // I strongly recommend you to have setting_id as foreign key in table voucher
            // So you could do 
            // $setting = Setting::where('Setting', 'weekly Subs')->where('Value', 10)->first();
            // $voucher->setting_id = $setting->id;
            $voucher->save();

            return redirect(action('RollController@index'))->with ('success', 'Member Paid with Vocuher');
        }
    }
    return redirect(action('RollController@index'));    
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however this appears to want to update records in the voucher table, where in fact I want to insert a new record. This for 2 reason, 1 I show a sum on the member summary page, and 2nd I want to see the history of use. Can you please update your answer for an insert and not an update using the member_id from the $roll. Thanks

Comment: Also you break the existing code base and I am presented with the following error:-  "Undefined variable: id". This is at the $roll = Roll::lockForUpdate()->find($id); line. Please remember the code I had above was working before

Comment: Updated accodingly, I might be wrong because I not sure your requirement and scope. If it is true please consider my table structure recommendation

Comment: @Brendan Appreciate if you could accept my answer if it helps to solve your question